# INVALID_ARGUMENT error when deploying Python GCP Cloud Function from either console or console.cloud.google.com/functions/edit

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm getting a `Build failed: Build has timed out` when trying to deploy a GCP cloud function where there is a dependancy on either `firebase_admin` or `google-cloud-firestore`.

The strange thing is that I have a whole host of functioning previously-deployed cloud functions with either of these listed in the requirements.txt, but when trying to redeploy those very same functions, the build fails.

First noticed this oddness this morning.

Below is the log entry for the failure

```
{
 insertId: "..."  
 logName: "projects/myproj8634928/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"  
 operation: {
  id: "operations/bW...M"   
  last: true   
  producer: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"   
 }
 protoPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"   
  authenticationInfo: {
   principalEmail: "...@gmail.com"    
  }
  methodName: "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction"   
  requestMetadata: {
   destinationAttributes: {
   }
   requestAttributes: {
   }
  }
  resourceName: "projects/myproj8634928/locations/europe-west2/functions/stupid-funcion"   
  serviceName: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"   
  status: {
   code: 3    
   message: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"    
  }
 }
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-02-05T16:01:36.150444022Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   function_name: "stupid-funcion"    
   project_id: "myproj8634928"    
   region: "europe-west2"    
  }
  type: "cloud_function"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 timestamp: "2020-02-05T16:01:35.198Z"  
}
```

And the contents of requirements.txt

```
firebase_admin
```

Answer (score 0):

This seem to have miraculously resolved itself between this posting and now.